# JQuery Component from specific selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, moodle

I am attempting to embed a component from another page on the same site into a page I am creating.

I have attempted

```
$("#result").load(URL #selector);
```

and

```
$("#result").html('<object data="https://example.com/mod/oublog/view.php?id=464" width="100%" height="100%" />');
```

The first query works but unfortunately, there are certain components that become cosmetic and don't function.

The second option embeds the entire page but retains all functionality on that page.

My question is whether you can use the second option but only display a certain element within that page and retain the functionality of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: you can do that and use css to hide the component which you dont want to show

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements and set the HTML contents of every matched element. You can use the second option but you have to find ways to display certain elements. This can be achieved as follows:

1. Use css/JS to toggle display hide.
2. Create events that if html is rendered, it will hide required elements.